# How to keep selenium step to be keep waiting for 1 hour?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, testng

Selecting a button on a page generates new window.
New window keeps loading for 1 hour as it will generate files from DataBase to local. How do I keep selenium to wait until for 1 hour??
i am trying to automate this scenario.
New window will have print statements after completion of db files generation in the background.

Comment: Hi! Can you post any code you have tried, or what research you have done?

Comment: Please don't write a test that will wait for one hour. There is too much that could go wrong, causing this tests to be flaky and therefore unreliable. Also this would significantly slow down your test suite and therefore not provide feedback in a timely fashion. Consider spillting up your test into separate smaller parts that can be tested. You ight need to set up your preconditions in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Well as we all should assume the file generations can take more or less time.

So you maybe need something more flexible, like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, waitForElementTimeout).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(webelement, "text", expected));
```

this code would wait until the Statement variable, which will be printed, gets the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `WebDriverWait` as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

use following to wait for 1 hour.

```
int hourInSecond = 3600;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, hourInSecond);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

1 hour = 3600 seconds;